# How to format Already installed mac hacintosh?

Tags: macos

I have installed **Mac hackintosh and Windows 8 Dual boot** in my laptop. I want to format my laptop but its not detecting my bootable pen drive of windows 10. Its **Every time starting with multi beast dual boot** so **How** can i **format** my laptop? Mainly i want to boot my pen drive but unable to boot from pen drive.

Answer (score 0):

You probably set the main HDD/SSD drive as the first boot device in BIOS so it's loading the hackintosh bootloader because of this wrong setting. You have to change the first boot device to your installer pendrive, then it should be OK!

In the Windows installer you can format your main HDD/SSD drive.